# Как проверить, открылась ли директория?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

По сути есть флешка. Надо проверить, может ли программа открыть её и с ней работать.

Знаю, что для файлов есть простая функция `is_open`, которая быстро может проверить, открылся файл или нет.

Может, есть что-то похожее для директорий?

Comment: А зачем "проверять"? Почему просто не попробовать с ней работать? Если не получится - сообщить об ошибке.

Comment: @Nikolay Так как эту операцию я собираюсь делать на многих флешках, то хочу быть уверен что каждая флешка открывается без проблем.

Comment: IMHO, ты сможешь быть в этом уверен, только если сделаешь реальную операцию (т.е. чтение, или что там еще)

Comment: Может попастся такая флешка в которой не будет файлов которые можно будет открыть для чтения.

Comment: res = fope(path_to_flash,'r') ;  если res == NULL , значит не можешь